# How to do a SELECT for total from beginning until the specified date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have `entry` table:

[image]

I need to do a SELECT to receive 'Date', 'Number of entries' (in that date), 'Total number of entries until that date'.

When I do the SELECT:

```
SELECT e1.*, 
(select count(*) from entry where date(dateCreated) <= e1.date) as Total 
from (
SELECT 
  DATE(e.dateCreated) as "Date", 
  count(e.dateCreated) as "No of Entries",
  sum( case when e.premium='Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as Premium,
  sum( case when e.free='Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as Free,
  sum( case when e.affiliateID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Affiliate

 FROM entry e
 WHERE e.competitionID=166
 GROUP BY DATE(e.dateCreated)
 ) as e1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

I've got a result table

[image]

but the column 'Total' has a wrong data.

How the correct select should be? Is this logic of select is the best and more efficient one?

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e88/15)

Comment: What should the correct value for Total be for each row? Is it the [sum of the other columns grouped by the date](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e88/19) (e.g. 1st row is 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 =2, not 7 ?). Currently, your subquery will simply count the number of records with a lower date, which decreases given that you are ordering the rows by `Date DESC`

Comment: I don't see the problem. Total is exactly "Total from beginning to this date".

Comment: Or do you mean "Total until that date, but not including that date", in this case simply change <= to < in the subquery.

Comment: There is 2 rows where competitionID != 166, so the maximum Total should be 5 instead of 7.

Comment: That date must be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just the 5 vs 7 that is off I think it is because that subquery in your select list, which accesses the inline view `e1` (which is filtered to competitionID = 166), is not itself filtered when also utilizing the original `entry` table (unfiltered). You have to filter the original table to that competitionID as well.

Notice line 3 in sql below (only change)

```
SELECT e1.*, 
(select count(*) from entry where date(dateCreated) <= e1.date
                              and competitionID=166) as Total 
from (
SELECT 
  DATE(e.dateCreated) as "Date", 
  count(e.dateCreated) as "No of Entries",
  sum( case when e.premium='Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as Premium,
  sum( case when e.free='Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as Free,
  sum( case when e.affiliateID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as Affiliate

 FROM entry e
 WHERE e.competitionID=166
 GROUP BY DATE(e.dateCreated)
 ) as e1
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e88/22/0

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!